# Can Drivers controll values in a way that does not break, when the Node Group is saved as an asset?

Tags: geometry-nodes, drivers, asset-browser

I am using Blender 3.5.1

**What I try to achieve and how I do it:**

I try to create a Geometry Node Group Asset for the Asset Browser (Planet Generator), which can be reused in different Projects and which works "Plug-n-Play", meaning I add the GeoNode Group to an Object and it turns into a planet that can be adjusted using the Group Input Values.

**The Problem:**

While using Drivers to control the values of the Shader Node Groups and Geometry Node Groups, I realized that they break when I use my Planet Generator Geometry Node Group on a different Object.

**My Question:**

Is there a way in Blender to create Drivers which are independent from the Object Instance the Nodes are attached to and that can be reused on other Objects or do I have to create an Asset from the Object itself with this Geometry Node Group attached?

Comment: This patch coming in the next release should help you with that. https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/pulls/105132

Comment: Oh, so that means currently I can only save the Object with GeoNodeGroup attached to it as a reusable asset? Thank you for the heads-up!

Comment: I have not tested the feature, so I wouldn't be able to give pointers, but I think this is the goal, yes - at least partially - dynamically recover some objects from the context :)

Comment: Great! Can't wait for the new update. Uhm, this is a stupid question, but I would award your answer as solving my question, but don't know how to do this if it is only a comment under my question. Sorry, I am totally new to Stackexchange.

Comment: Hehe well you can't ! I think it's not really worthy of an answer since the feature is not officially released :) So the canonical answer to your question, right now, with version 3.5, would be that it's not - yet - possible...

Answer (score 0):

Gorgious answered my question: It is not yet possible in Blender 3.5 but might be a feature implemented in the next version.